# Mathbf error in displaymath mode

Tags: amsmath, bold

I get a recurring error when working with `\begin{equation}`. If use `\mathbf` it returns an error saying that it will only work in math mode. Is there anyway around this?

The first column runs badly, the second and third run fine but are displayed in single line mode which is not what I was hoping for. Any ideas?

I'm running the `amsmath` package.

```
\begin{table}[hptb!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}=\frac{\partial{\mathbf{f}_{T}}}{\partial{\mathbf{\ddot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
\end{equation}
&
\(
\mathbf{C}=\frac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}}{\partial{\mathbf{\dot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
\)
&
\(
\mathbf{K} = \frac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{f}_{V}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}} {\partial{\mathbf{q}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}} 
\)
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't use `equation` in a tabular cell with `c`. If really needed, use a parbox cell, e.g. `p{3cm}`, but I think, you should rather use `align` or `alignedat` here

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "single line mode". Do you maybe mean inline math mode?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a simpler code like this:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{M} & =\frac{\partial{\mathbf{f}_{T}}}{\partial{\mathbf{\ddot{q}}}} \Biggr|_{q=q_{e}}
&
\mathbf{C} & =\frac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}}{\partial{\mathbf{\dot{q}}}} \Biggr|_{q=q_{e}}
&
\mathbf{K} & = \frac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{f}_{V}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}} {\partial{\mathbf{q}}} \Biggr|_{q=q_{e}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since ncons seems to be a name, I would go with \textup{ncons} instead, wouldn't you?

Comment: I wondered indeed. Unless it should be $n\text{cons}$? I don't see what it refers to. Maybe also $q_e$ should be $q_\text{e}$.

Answer (score 1):

`equation` can't be used in a `c` - like cell -- use `p` for this.

However, I recommend an `array` or `alignat*` environment rather for this setup, since the `equation` will also display an equation number which might not be requested at all.

I also changed from `\frac` to `\dfrac`. Most likely, the text-likely exponents should be typeset with `\text{ncons}` etc., but I leave this to the O.P.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{M}=\dfrac{\partial{\mathbf{f}_{T}}}{\partial{\mathbf{\ddot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
&
\mathbf{C}=\dfrac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}}{\partial{\mathbf{\dot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
&
\mathbf{K} = \dfrac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{f}_{V}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}} {\partial{\mathbf{q}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
\end{array}
$
\end{center}

With 'alignat*' 
\begin{center}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbf{M}=\dfrac{\partial{\mathbf{f}_{T}}}{\partial{\mathbf{\ddot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
&\quad
\mathbf{C}=\dfrac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}}{\partial{\mathbf{\dot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
&\quad
\mathbf{K} = \dfrac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{f}_{V}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}} {\partial{\mathbf{q}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{center}


However -- not recommended:

\begin{table}[hptb!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}cc}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}=\dfrac{\partial{\mathbf{f}_{T}}}{\partial{\mathbf{\ddot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
\end{equation}
&
\(
\mathbf{C}=\dfrac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}}{\partial{\mathbf{\dot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
\)
&
\(
\mathbf{K} = \dfrac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{f}_{V}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}} {\partial{\mathbf{q}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}} 
\)
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some comments about your code, listed in no particular order:

- `\partial` does not take an argument. Hence, don't write `\partial{\mathbf{f}_{T}}`; go for the simpler `\partial\mathbf{f}_T`. You won't get an error message if you add an extra layer of braces; however, doing so does clutter up the code needlessly.
- None of the `\substack` directives are needed. Omitting them would also help declutter the code.
- If you need to show a display-math equation in a float (such as a `table` or `figure`), don't number the equation directly. Instead, use the `\caption`-`\label`-`\ref` mechanism to cross-reference the float that contains the equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Three partial derivative expressions}
\[
\mathbf{M}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}_T}{\partial\mathbf{\ddot{q}}} \biggr|_{q=q_e}
\qquad
\mathbf{C}=\frac{\partial(\mathbf{f}_T+ \mathbf{Q}^{\mathrm{ncons}})}
    {\partial\mathbf{\dot{q}}} \biggr|_{q=q_e}
\qquad
\mathbf{K} = \frac{\partial(\mathbf{f}_T+\mathbf{f}_{V}
    + \mathbf{Q}^{\mathrm{ncons}})} {\partial\mathbf{q}} \biggr|_{q=q_e} 
\]
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array environment is like a math version of tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hptb!]
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{M}=\frac{\partial{\mathbf{f}_{T}}}{\partial{\mathbf{\ddot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
&
\mathbf{C}=\frac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}}{\partial{\mathbf{\dot{q}}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}}
&
\mathbf{K} = \frac{\partial{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{f}_{V}+\mathbf{Q}^{ncons})}} {\partial{\mathbf{q}}} \Bigr|_{\substack{q=q_{e}}} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest dropping `tabular`; I don't think you want `table`, either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ncons}{{\mathrm{ncons}}}
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}=\pder{\mathbf{f}_{T}}{\ddot{\mathbf{q}}} \bigg|_{q=q_{e}}
\hspace{1em minus 1em}
\mathbf{C}=\pder{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{Q}^\ncons)}{\dot{\mathbf{q}}} \bigg|_{q=q_{e}}
\hspace{1em minus 1em}
\mathbf{K}=\pder{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{f}_{V}+\mathbf{Q}^\ncons)}{\mathbf{q}} \bigg|_{q=q_{e}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\mathbf{M}=\pder{\mathbf{f}_{T}}{\ddot{\mathbf{q}}} \bigg|_{q=q_{e}}
\qquad\qquad
\mathbf{C}=\pder{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{Q}^\ncons)}{\dot{\mathbf{q}}} \bigg|_{q=q_{e}}
\\[1ex]
\mathbf{K}=\pder{(\mathbf{f}_{T}+\mathbf{f}_{V}+\mathbf{Q}^\ncons)}{\mathbf{q}} \bigg|_{q=q_{e}}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]